# T-SQL Space Before Capital Letters

Tags: t-sql

The question is self explanatory. Could you please point out a way to put spaces between each capital letter of a string.

```
SELECT dbo.SpaceBeforeCap('ThisIsATestString')
```

would result in

```
This Is A Test String.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server 2005 or later, this modified from code taken here: http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/case-sensitive-sql-split-function.aspx

```
CREATE FUNCTION SpaceBeforeCap
(
 @str nvarchar(max)
)
returns nvarchar(max)
as
begin

declare @i int, @j int
declare @returnval nvarchar(max)
set @returnval = ''
select @i = 1, @j = len(@str)

declare @w nvarchar(max)

while @i <= @j
begin
 if substring(@str,@i,1) = UPPER(substring(@str,@i,1)) collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
 begin
  if @w is not null
  set @returnval = @returnval + ' ' + @w
  set @w = substring(@str,@i,1)
 end
 else
  set @w = @w + substring(@str,@i,1)
 set @i = @i + 1
end
if @w is not null
 set @returnval = @returnval + ' ' + @w

return ltrim(@returnval)

end
```

This can then be called just as you have suggested above.

Comment: This assumes that the data does not contain any special XML characters. Probably safer to just hack the function directly to do the concatenation rather than inserting to a table variable.

Comment: @Martin -- agreed; I've modified it to just do a straight concatenation.

Answer (score 11):

This will add spaces only if the previous and next character is lowercase. That way 'MyABCAnalysis' will be 'My ABC Analysis'.

I added a check for a previous space too. Since some of our strings are prefixed with 'GR_' and some also contain underscores, we can use the replace function as follows:

select dbo.GR_SpaceBeforeCap(replace('GR_ABCAnalysis_Test','_',' '))
Returns 'GR ABC Analysis Test'

```
CREATE FUNCTION GR_SpaceBeforeCap (
    @str nvarchar(max)
)
returns nvarchar(max)
as
begin

declare
    @i int, @j int
,   @cp nchar, @c0 nchar, @c1 nchar
,   @result nvarchar(max)

select
    @i = 1
,   @j = len(@str)
,   @result = ''

while @i <= @j
begin
    select
        @cp = substring(@str,@i-1,1)
    ,   @c0 = substring(@str,@i+0,1)
    ,   @c1 = substring(@str,@i+1,1)

    if @c0 = UPPER(@c0) collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
    begin
        -- Add space if Current is UPPER 
        -- and either Previous or Next is lower
        -- and Previous or Current is not already a space
        if @c0 = UPPER(@c0) collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
        and (
                @cp <> UPPER(@cp) collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
            or  @c1 <> UPPER(@c1) collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
        )
        and @cp <> ' '
        and @c0 <> ' '
            set @result = @result + ' '
    end -- if @co

    set @result = @result + @c0
    set @i = @i + 1
end -- while

return @result
end
```

Comment: This works for me and my heterogeneous environment where we have Oracle style naming mixed with Camel Case. We often end up with a mix of UNDERSCORES_and_FirstLetterCapitalized object names.

Answer (score 6):

This function combines previous answers. Selectively choose to preserve adjacent CAPS:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SpaceBeforeCap (
    @InputString NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @PreserveAdjacentCaps BIT
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE
    @i INT, @j INT,
        @previous NCHAR, @current NCHAR, @next NCHAR,
        @result NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT
    @i = 1,
        @j = LEN(@InputString),
        @result = ''

WHILE @i <= @j
BEGIN
    SELECT
        @previous = SUBSTRING(@InputString,@i-1,1),
                @current = SUBSTRING(@InputString,@i+0,1),
                @next = SUBSTRING(@InputString,@i+1,1)

    IF @current = UPPER(@current) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
    BEGIN
        -- Add space if Current is UPPER 
        -- and either Previous or Next is lower or user chose not to preserve adjacent caps
        -- and Previous or Current is not already a space
        IF @current = UPPER(@current) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
        AND (
                            @previous <> UPPER(@previous) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
                            OR  @next <> UPPER(@next) collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
                            OR  @PreserveAdjacentCaps = 0
        )
        AND @previous <> ' '
        AND @current <> ' '
            SET @result = @result + ' '
    END 

    SET @result = @result + @current
    SET @i = @i + 1
END 

RETURN @result
END

GO
SELECT dbo.SpaceBeforeCap('ThisIsASampleDBString', 1)
GO
SELECT dbo.SpaceBeforeCap('ThisIsASampleDBString', 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid loops altogether, use of a tally table can help here. If you are running on SQL 2022, then the `generate_series` function can remove even this dependency.  This method will be significantly faster than iterating through a loop.

```sql
create function core.ufnAddSpaceBeforeCapital
(
    @inputString nvarchar(max)
)
returns nvarchar(max)
as
begin

    declare @outputString nvarchar(max)

    select 
        @outputString = string_agg(iif(t.value = 1, upper(substring(@inputString,t.value,1)),iif(ascii(substring(@inputString,t.value,1)) between 65 and 90, ' ','') + substring(@inputString,t.value,1)),'')
    from 
        generate_series(1,cast(len(@inputString) as int)) t

    return @outputString

end
```

The scalar function is not inlineable, so I've provided an alternative inline table-valued function if that's what you need.

```sql
create function core.ufnAddSpaceBeforeCapitalITVF
(
    @inputString nvarchar(max)
)
returns table
as
return
(
    select 
        string_agg(iif(t.value = 1, upper(substring(@inputString,t.value,1)),iif(ascii(substring(@inputString,t.value,1)) between 65 and 90, ' ','') + substring(@inputString,t.value,1)),'') as outputString
    from 
        generate_series(1,cast(len(@inputString) as int)) t
)

end
```

Answer (score 1):

CLR and regular expressions or 26 replace statements a case sensitive collate clause and a trim.

Answer (score 1):

Another strategy would be to check the ascii value of each character:

```
create function SpaceBeforeCap
 (@str nvarchar(max))
returns nvarchar(max)
as
begin
  declare @result nvarchar(max)= left(@str, 1), 
          @i int = 2

  while @i <= len(@str)
  begin
    if ascii(substring(@str, @i, 1)) between 65 and 90
      select @result += ' '
    select @result += substring(@str, @i, 1)
    select @i += 1 
  end

  return @result
 end

 /***
  SELECT dbo.SpaceBeforeCap('ThisIsATestString') 
 **/
```

Answer (score 1):

While I really like the char looping answers I was not thrilled with the performance.  I have found this performs in a fraction of the time for my use case.

```
CREATE function SpaceBeforeCap
    (@examine nvarchar(max))
returns nvarchar(max)
as
begin

DECLARE @index as INT

SET @index = PatIndex( '%[^ ][A-Z]%', @examine COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN)
WHILE @index > 0 BEGIN

    SET @examine = SUBSTRING(@examine, 1, @index) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(@examine, @index + 1, LEN(@examine))
    SET @index = PatIndex( '%[^ ][A-Z]%', @examine COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN)

END

RETURN LTRIM(@examine)

end
```

This makes use of the fact that 
[case sensitive pattern search only works in some collations](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15307.patindex-case-sensitive-search.aspx).  The character class `[^ ]` means anything except space, so as we add the missing spaces we match farther into the string until it is complete.